# Https and Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, https

I have a WCF Service hosting in web site IIS, in Windows Server 2012.

Site Bindings has only

> https  myhostname.labsoa 443

I call URL in IExplorer **https://myhostname.labsoa/RoutingService.svc**

I want ONLY call to Wcf Service using ***https***

Note: replace real value by *myhostname.labsoa*

I get the message error:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the
>   endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes
>   are [https]

In my WCF Service host, I have this configuration files:

**web.config**

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings configSource="Config\system.serviceModel.bindings.config"/>
    <services configSource="Config\system.serviceModel.services.config"/>
    <behaviors configSource="Config\system.serviceModel.behaviors.config"/>
    <client configSource="Config\system.serviceModel.client.config"/>
    <routing configSource="Config\system.serviceModel.routing.config"/>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment 
     aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"
     multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Config\system.serviceModel.behaviors.config**

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="routingData">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"
                       httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <routing filterTableName="routingTable1" routeOnHeadersOnly="false" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**Config\system.serviceModel.bindings.config**

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Default" closeTimeout="00:05:00"
             openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
             allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding_Default" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">

     <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      </security>
       </binding>

  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Config\system.serviceModel.services.config**

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="routingData" 
      name="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add  baseAddress="https://myhostname.labsoa/RoutingService.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              name="reqReplyEndpoint"
              contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter" />
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange"  />
    <endpoint
              address="/Contacto"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter"
              name="ContactoRouting"
              bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_Default"
              />
```

Any suggestions about it?

Comment: Your bindings in Config\system.serviceModel.bindings.config are not https.

Comment: I use ***Transport*** in node **security mode="Transport"**. Secure only Transport.

Comment: Have you configured an SSL certificate in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoing configuration doesnt have bindinginConfiguration.
Following configuration

```
<endpoint address=""
          binding="wsHttpBinding"
          name="reqReplyEndpoint"
          contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter" />
```

should be

```
<endpoint address=""
          binding="wsHttpBinding"
          name="reqReplyEndpoint"
          bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_Default"
          contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter" />
```

Comment: What's about **mex** _binding="mexHttpBinding"_ ?